# How do I Force db commit of a single save in django-orm in a celery task

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, celery

I am using django and celery. I have a long running celery task and I would like it to report progress. I am doing this:

```
@shared_task
def do_the_job(tracker_id, *args, **kwargs):
    while condition:
        #Do a long operation
        tracker = ProgressTracker.objects.get(pk=tracker_id)
        tracker.task_progress = F('task_progress') + 1
        tracker.last_update = timezone.now()
        tracker.save(update_fields=['task_progress', 'last_update'])
```

The problem is that the view that is supposed to show the progress to the user cannot see the updates until the task finishes. Is there a way to get the django orm to ignore transactions for just this one table? Or just this one write?

Comment: You can use `flower` to track the task progress.
https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That looks like a good ui for our ops team, but I just want to show the user a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bound tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks) to define [custom states](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) for your tasks and set/update the state during execution:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def show_progress(self, n):
    for i in range(n):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': i, 'total': n})
```

You can dump the state of currently executing tasks to get the progress:

```
>>> from celery import Celery
>>> app = Celery('proj')
>>> i = app.control.inspect()
>>> i.active()
```

Comment: Interesting. How would that work with tasks that are actually big graphs of groups and chords? Because I have some of those too.